# Exposing Extension methods in WCF datacontract

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-client

Is it possible to expose extension methods on objects which are data contracts in WCF?

Here is an example:

```
[DataContract]
public class Customer
{
    [DataMember]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public Product CurrentProduct { get; set; }

    public Customer DeepCopy()
    {
        //Do Something else. For example just return a new instance
        return new Customer();
    }      
}

[DataContract]
public class Product
{
    [DataMember]
    public int ID;

    [DataMember]
    public int Name;
}
```

In the customer class there is a deep copy method. How do I expose this to the client?

Comment: Can you give more information on what you are looking for? Are you wanting to create an extension method for a specific type, data contracts in general, or somehow get the extension method across the wire?

Comment: how about showing what you want to extend, and maybe the answer will be how to implement that without trying to extend a serialized type.

Comment: Why do you need that?  Why not have the client(s) new up the Customer if they need one, but in reality, since this is WCF, Customer will be created by the service and given to the client or vice versa.  Why do you need the DataContract to do that?

Comment: @Mark W. I don't want to create a new in the deepCopy. thai just to show an example I did that. Lets say I am doing some reflection and copying the members to a new object and then returning that object.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can only expose properties in a WCF DataContract, not methods.

Answer (score 1):

You can almost do this using the "Reuse types" feature. Unfortunately for your case, it only allows the reuse of types which are actually used by the service as input or output parameters. Your class holding the extension methods will be a static class and will therefore not appear as an input parameter nor as a return type.